# Implementing loop of handlebars.js on nameless object or array

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

All of `Handlebars` examples are implementing loops with array or object names, but my json array doesn't have any names.

My data is something like:

```
[
    {"$id":"1","SiteItemID":1,"Title":"Title 1","CreateDate":"2014-06-19T14:12:22.157"},
    {"$id":"2","SiteItemID":2,"Title":"Title 2","CreateDate":"2014-06-19T14:12:22.157"},
    {"$id":"2","SiteItemID":3,"Title":"Title 3","CreateDate":"2014-06-19T14:12:22.157"},
]
```

I want to use them in table rows and my html is something like:

```
{{#each object}}
<tr data-id="{{this.SiteItemID}}">
    <td class="title col-xs-8">
        {{this.Title}}
    </td>
    <td class="date text-right col-xs-2">
        {{this.CreateDate}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{else}}
No Content
{{/each}}
```

And I'm putting them together with following JS code:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.101.223:81/api/siteitem'
        , success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
}
function showData() {
    var data = getData();
    var template = $("#itemlist-table").html();
    var handlebarsTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
    var output = handlebarsTemplate(data);
    $("#mainbody").html(output);
}
showData();
```

And I have tried `{{#each object}}` and `{{#each array}}`, but both of them result in 'No Content'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use {{#each []}}

```
{{#each []}}
<tr data-id="{{this.SiteItemID}}">
    <td class="title col-xs-8">
        {{this.Title}}
    </td>
    <td class="date text-right col-xs-2">
        {{this.CreateDate}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{else}}
No Content
{{/each}}
```

here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ckross01/K49xy/